# Using a Query Object In A C# Expression to Return A different type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, expression

I currently have a data object for the sake of argument I'll call it foo...

```
public class Foo 
{
   public int IndexedKey { get; set;}
   public string NonIndexedData {get; set;}
}
```

I have a generic repository that I want to query this object with, however due to permissions to the database I'm not allowed to do a full table scan. I've therefore been tasked with creating safe query objects.

```
public class FooQuery
{
    public int IndexedKey
}
```

The generic repository allows an arbitrary predicate and it currently has an implementaation similar to the following...

```
public class FooRepo : IGenericRepo<Foo>
{
    private ICollection<Foo> _allFooRecords; //Imagine this is populated

    public ICollection<Foo> GetWhere(Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> criteria)
    {
        return _allFooRecords.Where(criteria.Compile())
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following...

```
public class FooRepo : IGenericRepo<Foo, FooQuery>
{
    private ICollection<Foo> _allFooRecords; //Imagine this is populated

    public ICollection<Foo> GetWhere(Expression<Func<FooQuery, bool>> criteria)
    {
        return _allFooRecords.Where(criteria.Compile())
    }
}
```

The above won't compile. I know that FooQuery's properties definitely contain the right fields that match what is the indexed property of the Foo class, but I can no longer user the criteria.Compile because it will return a function that is incompatible with searching a Foo collection. Is there a way to make this work with the above signature, and what would I need to change about my implementation to get this to work correctly.

Many Thanks

Comment: see my answer, if you have an question let me know, otherwise please mark as resolved

Comment: oops, I know what you want to do: FooQuery is actually kind of your viewmodel, and Foo is your real entity, but you want to query DB  by an expression which is based on your view model. so you want a solution to map your viewmodel to real model, yes?

Comment: Try returning IQueryable<> instead of ICollection. Won't fix your problem, but may help greatly improve performance and might be a part of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your requirement is: Automatically translate view model expression `Expression<Func<FooQuery, bool>>` to real model expression `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>`. `FooQuery` is actually your `ViewModel`, but `Foo` is real `Model`.

Automapper could do the magic.

```
//wrap the translate in base class, so you don't have to do it in each repo
public class BaseRepo<TEntity, TViewMode> : IGenericRepo<TEntity, TViewMode>
{
    ....
    public IWhatever<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TViewMode, bool>> vmExpression)
    {
        var expression = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>(vmExpression);
        return whateverDataOrQuery.Where(expression);
    }

}
```

Full official document is here:

Expression Translation: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).md

Comment: I think their architecture is broken, they probably should be returning a FooQuery, and use automappers ProjectTo instead, but automapper should help in both senarios +1

Comment: yes. full official document is here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).md

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of automapper. That sounds like a reasonable way to do things. I'll admit the architechture needs work, but we're early days and if the above works it'll get me out of a jam. I'll try this tomorrow and accept the answer if it works. Many Thanks.

Comment: auto-mapper is widely used in project. just enjoy it.